# how to store data input best java

Tags: java

i communicate to ilog via java and get a textfile output which looks like this:

```
18
3
PRODUKT:1:RESSOURCE:1:0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:2:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:3:0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   16  0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
PRODUKT:2:RESSOURCE:1:0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:2:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:3:0   0   0   13  0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   13  20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
PRODUKT:3:RESSOURCE:1:0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:2:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:3:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   12  0   12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   21  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
PRODUKT:4:RESSOURCE:1:0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:2:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:3:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   8   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
PRODUKT:5:RESSOURCE:1:0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:2:0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
RESSOURCE:3:0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ;
```

and etc.

i want to turn one row into one int[];
and then put this int[] fields into a map or something.
So there would be a  map with keys like "Produkt:4Ressource:1" and values with the int[];

i just want to know which is the best collection for me to store data like this?
Map<"String",int[]> is that even possible? or do i need an object class which contains an []? Maybe thats better way of coding. Not sure.

Comment: You have an Object oriented language, so making an Object to represent your data is probably best. As for holding the values, a list or an array are fine

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap would be a good option to store. You can retrieve the values from it when you need.